# Match from Javascript to Android Java

Tags: android, math

Help the example in the language Java Android?

```
if(profile<50) scalar=0.85;
if(profile>=50) scalar=0.7;

rimWidthMin = (Math.round(((width*scalar)*0.03937)*2))/2;
rimWidthMax = (rimWidthMin+1.5);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double scalar = 0.;

if(profile<50) scalar=0.85;
if(profile>=50) scalar=0.7;

double rimWidthMin = (Math.round(((width*scalar)*0.03937)*2))/2;
double rimWidthMax = (rimWidthMin+1.5);
```

Nearly same :P

Comment: Out of interest, I work in C# and as far as I've seen we rarely (nor do most example code) use doubles instead of floats. When I was thought back in highschool about Java we used Double instead and I notice that it's a very common practice to use the bigger variable type (double). Is there is reason for this? I know a lot of math automatically casts into a double (say 1 / 4 will be cast into a double?). Seems like allocating a much larger variable type will end up a waste of ram space for non-super precision float point calculations...

Comment: I understand, but the essence of the problem in the calculation of the nearest millimeter